# Tabulating and printing a frequency distribution through NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, frequency-distribution

I'm trying to get NLTK to tabulate trigrams across an entire corpus of 12,000 text files and then print the frequency distributions of each trigram out to a file but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TPNngrams2.py", line 19, in <module>
    fdisttab = fdist.tabulate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 281, in tabulate
     print("%4s" % samples[i], end=' ')
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Here's the code:

```
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk import FreqDist

#this imports the text files in the folder into corpus called speeches
corpus_root = '/Users/root'
speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*\.txt')

print "Finished importing corpus"
fdist = nltk.FreqDist()  # Empty distribution

for filename in speeches.fileids():
    (str(trigram) for trigram in nltk.trigrams(speeches.words(filename)))
    fdist.update(nltk.trigrams(speeches.words(filename)))

fdisttab = fdist.tabulate()
print fdisttab
f = open('freqdists.txt', 'w+')
f.write(fdisttab)
f.close()

print "All done. Check file."
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I have no idea how to start tackling this.

Comment: I really don't know?

Comment: Your problem is that you have a tuple where it expects a simple string. It's a hack, but you can change the body of your for loop to convert it manually; ie, `(str(trigram) for trigram in nltk.trigrams(speeches.words(filename)))` - if you want different formatting you can of course do it manually.

Comment: added that and got the same error!

Comment: I recreated this and don't get the error -- odd. Can you update the post with your changes (or pastebin) so I can see what you're actually doing?

Comment: Updated! Did I put it in the wrong place?

Comment: Your corpus is really sitting in `/Users/root/*.txt`? That's just wrong...

Comment: Anyway @ap is right; and you should pass `str(trigram)` to the frequency distribution. Where you put it it's doing nothing. Try to understand what your code is doing before the assignments get hopelessly complex.

Comment: Well, you'd need to call `fdist.update` on that generator I provided - on its own it doesn't change anything.